# AWK regex convert 3 letter word beginning with 'a' to uppercase

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk

I have my regex expression to find 3 letter words beginning with "a"...

```
\b[aA][a-z]{2}\b
```

(seems to work, according to this! check it out: http://rubular.com/r/Jil0E4WZnW)

Now I need to know how to take that result and replace the lowercase word with the three letter word in uppercase.

Thanks!

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/caplitalizechange-to-uppercase-first.html

Comment: What you posted is a regular expression. Different tools understand different regular expression formats, e.g. BREs vs EREs, some will understand abbreviations like \b, some will only accept POSIX character classes like [[:blank:]]. etc. so you can't just write an RE and say `seems to work` as what that RE means will depend greatly on which tool you are using. You tagged this with several tools none of which is ruby, and then provided a link to apparently a Ruby RE evaluator so we don't know what you want to do. Show sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Ed... Sorry I wasn't more clear. I am trying to use unix to create an awk script. I want to use gsub for Ass, Ant, and Ape and find those words and then replace them with eitehr ASS, ANT, or APE. How can I get gsub to find these words, replace them with their capital counterpart, and then print only the modified line?

Answer (score 0):

call toupper function in awk:

```
echo "Abc" | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
```

gets you:

```
ABC
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I am trying to use unix to create an awk script. I want to use gsub for Ass, Ant, and Ape and find those words and then replace them with eitehr ASS, ANT, or APE. How can I get gsub to find these words, replace them with their capital counterpart, and then print only the modified line?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `uc($string);` command of PERL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Sed like this:

```
echo 'Ass ass ant Ant' | sed -re 's/\ba[a-z]{2}\b/\U&/gI'
```

*(with your example string)*

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how i could do this in AWK?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `tr`:

```
echo "Abc" | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I am trying to use unix to create an awk script. I want to use gsub for Ass, Ant, and Ape and find those words and then replace them with eitehr ASS, ANT, or APE. How can I get gsub to find these words, replace them with their capital counterpart, and then print only the modified line?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe '$_=~s/\b([aA][a-z]{2})\b/\U$1/g;' your_file
```

tested:

```
> echo "Abc ab Ab" | perl -pe '$_=~s/\b([aA][a-z]{2})\b/\U$1/g;'
ABC ab Ab
>
```

Taken from [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/caplitalizechange-to-uppercase-first.html)
Here is the awk version:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      if((length($i)==3) && $i~/[aA][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]/)
      $i=toupper($i)
     }1' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to do this but in AWK?

Answer (score 0):

This solution "cheats" because it uses a loop and sub instead of gsub, but it is in awk and it works.

```
echo "abc Ape baaa ab abcd ant" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i)==3){sub(/[aA][a-z]{2}/,toupper($i),$i)};print}'
```